# dplyr if else without the else/ conditional mutate in one chunk

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to add a column to my dataframe based on if a string is detected in another column. I have done this in two chunks of code and then merged them together, but I am trying to streamline my code so that there is less to type out in the future. I also noticed I performed a join incorrectly on a dataset I've been working with for months, so the fewers joins, the better.

Here is what currently works for me, but feels unnecessarily long.

```
dtc_final2022<- dtc_final1 %>% 
  filter (str_detect(detection_timestamp_utc, "2022")) %>%
  mutate(Year = "2022") 

dtc_final2021 <-  dtc_final1 %>% 
  filter (str_detect(detection_timestamp_utc, "2021")) %>%
  mutate(Year = "2021")

dtc_final2 <- full_join(dtc_final2021, dtc_final2022)
```

dtc_final1 is a dataset with timestamps from many years. I am only interested in adding a "year" to timestamps that contain 2021 and 2022. In the future, I will add 2023 and 2024.

This is what I would like to do, but in doing so, I replace the previous year with NA. Is there a way to run an ifelse function without the 'else'? Also, please remember that I cant use the other year as the 'else' since in the future, I will have 4 years to deal with, and not just 2.

```
dtc_final2 <- dtc_final1 %>%
  mutate(Year = ifelse(str_detect(detection_timestamp_utc, "2021"), "2021", NA),
         Year = ifelse(str_detect(detection_timestamp_utc, "2022"), "2022", NA))
```

I try to do everyling in dplyr but if a for loop does the trick, then I guess I'll buck up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide `dput(head(dtc_final1,6))`. Perhaps all you need is this: `mutate(dtc_final1, Year=str_extract(detection_timestamp_utc, "^202[12]"))`?

Comment: @langtang  `mutate(dtc_final1, Year=str_extract(detection_timestamp_utc, "^202[12]"))` seems to work perfectly. Can you explain what the last argument does?

Comment: its also unlikely you need to use string extraction/detection methods. if your timestamp is actually just a date, use a date part extraction function such as `lubridate::year()` or `data.table::year()`

Comment: @langtang ... I'm feeling pretty dumb right now. Thats so much easier. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `str_extract()` rather than `str_detect()` here, and use a regular expression that captures both of the years of interest:

```
mutate(dtc_final1, Year=str_extract(detection_timestamp_utc, "^202[12]"))
```

Answer (score 1):

For multiple sequential/nested `ifelse`s, we can use `case_when`.

```
dtc_final2 <- dtc_final1 %>% 
    mutate(Year = case_when(str_detect(detection_timestamp_utc, "2021") ~ 2021,
                            str_detect(detection_timestamp_utc, "2022") ~ 2022,
                            TRUE ~ NA)
```

There are likely better options for this specific case, hard to tell without seeing the data.
if `detection_timestamp_utc` is a proper date object, we likely hava a better way with the `lubridate` package.

```
dtc_final2 <- dtc_final1 %>% 
    mutate(Year = lubidate::year(as.Date(detection_timestamp_utc)))
```

Comment: `Case 3 (str_detect(detection_timestamp_utc, "2021") ~ 2021) must be a two-sided
  formula, not a logical vector` is my error message. The data is literally just a column of dates. Ex: 2022-05-10 10:00:00

Comment: Ok, I believe you do not have the latest verstion of dplyr, so my updated answer may wokr better. For dplyr < 1.1.0, we have to use `TRUE ~ NA` instead of `.default = NA`

Comment: Moreover, I strongly suggest properly handling dates as dates and not character, as you may see from my second method

Comment: Yeah I have no idea why I didn't think to use lubridate::year. Makes so much more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, And if the column already is of date_time type, we can also obviate the `as.Date` part.

Comment: @GuesdesBF I am trying to use your solution to fill in other types of data now, and I am getting the same error message. Basically, I have a df with 2 variables: Name and Region. Some of my Region values are missing and I am trying to manually fill them using mutate(Region = case_when(str_detect(Name, "Desired Name") ~ "Region Name", .default = NA)), but to no avail. Thanks

Comment: df$Region[df$Station == "Station Name"] <- "Region" (in base)

Comment: did you check my second comment above? Do you have dplyr vs 1.1.0 or higher?

Comment: Yes, I tried both TRUE ~ NA and .default = NA but neither work. I am running dplyr_1.0.10 , even after reinstalling it prior to running both NA options.

Comment: I can only help so much without a proper reproducible example. Maybe if you can provide one in a new question?